# How to access multiple encrypted LVM partitions all belonging to OpenSUSE in another distro?

Tags: partition, lvm, opensuse, encryption

Good day everyone. I accidentaly deleted the partitions containing `/boot` and `/boot/efi` while I was trying to remove Fedora 37. Ever since then, I cannot access OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and Windows 11. These are the outputs when I run the following commands:

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204885504 bytes, 1953525167 sectors
Disk model: Expansion HDD   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 950BB753-E2D3-05EF-44A5-AD62299E4108

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  202337671  202335624  96.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  202337672  202403207      65536    32M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  202405888  546150399  343744512 163.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  546152448  796151807  249999360 119.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  796153856 1953523711 1157369856 551.9G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKNU512GZ                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D4D24E91-6DA9-4FEC-9BD8-BBDD412F9D27

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     526335    524288   256M Linux LVM
/dev/nvme0n1p2  609458176  632897535  23439360  11.2G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p3    2480128    2512895     32768    16M Linux LVM
/dev/nvme0n1p4  283641856  609458175 325816320 155.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5    3481600  283641855 280160256 133.6G Linux LVM
/dev/nvme0n1p6    2512896    3481599    968704   473M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p8  632897536  632930303     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p9  632930304  998623231 365692928 174.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p10 998623232 1000212479   1589248   776M Windows recovery environment

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-069014fc-87ae-4213-89f9-da62a3fcbbc2: 155.36 GiB, 166815858688 bytes, 325812224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/zram0: 5.7 GiB, 6115819520 bytes, 1493120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram1: 5.7 GiB, 6115819520 bytes, 1493120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

The partitions I want to gain access to are `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, `/dev/nvme0n1p3`, and `/dev/nvme0n1p5`. However, when I ran `psv`, it doesn't show anything. What can I do to gain access to the files in my system again? I'm not planning on making it boot to OpenSUSE again, I just want to be able to access my files there.

**Additional Information:**
`neofetch`

```
                     ./o.                  mitsuki@Zhaya 
                   ./sssso-                ------------- 
                 `:osssssss+-              OS: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64 
               `:+sssssssssso/.            Host: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X515EA_X515EA 1.0 
             `-/ossssssssssssso/.          Kernel: 6.1.9-arch1-1 
           `-/+sssssssssssssssso+:`        Uptime: 1 hour, 6 mins 
         `-:/+sssssssssssssssssso+/.       Packages: 1179 (pacman), 11 (flatpak) 
       `.://osssssssssssssssssssso++-      Shell: fish 3.6.0 
      .://+ssssssssssssssssssssssso++:     Resolution: 1920x1080 
    .:///ossssssssssssssssssssssssso++:    WM: i3 
  `:////ssssssssssssssssssssssssssso+++.   Theme: Adwaita [GTK2], Arc-Darker [GTK3] 
`-////+ssssssssssssssssssssssssssso++++-   Icons: Adwaita [GTK2], Qogir [GTK3] 
 `..-+oosssssssssssssssssssssssso+++++/`   Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
   ./++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++/:.     Terminal Font: Source Code Pro 10 
  `:::::::::::::::::::::::::------``       CPU: 11th Gen Intel i3-1115G4 (4) @ 4.100GHz 
                                           GPU: Intel Tiger Lake-LP GT2 [UHD Graphics G4] 
                                           Memory: 5597MiB / 11665MiB
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the partition with the encrypted content needs to be unlocked. This will provide another "virtual" block device, which the LVM tooling will be able to access.

Run `lsblk -f` and `lsblk` to see the available "physical" disk devices and their partitions. At least one of them will likely show `crypto` in the `FSTYPE` column.

Then try

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/feaf408d-3257-4850-b597-bbca1dc651df cr_my_lvm
```

which will ask for the passphrase and then create the new "virtual" block device.

Check `lsblk -f` and `lsblk` again if it did create a `cr_my_lvm` thing.

Depending on the available tooling, the LVM might be already active. If not, proceed how you would normally do without an encrypted partition.

Comment: Good day. I ran `lsblk -f` and it showed me the three Encrypted LVM Partitions belonging to OpenSUSE. The partitions are found in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7BCRsvhk). 

I ran `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/f62da9e6-df20-4eea-b5bc-f1a42fca48a6 clvm` to open `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, but I also want to open the other partitions, as they might also contain files. How can I open the three partitions in such a way that I can access all the files they contain without any data loss?

Comment: I think you need to run the `cryptsetup ...` command for each and every block device, like `6bbaacab-50a5-4e25-812f-2d9c57d8f0bc` and `d25e4211-4a3a-4fb4-9185-159513d710ad` in your case. Make sure to use a unique name for each one, which means something else than `clvm`